# Is it possible to bypass the admin approval step based on a particular condition?

Tags: users

Potential scenario:

Allow users with a particular email address or token to skip the admin approval step and have their account approved ie: it sends the password/login link out immediately and they don't receive the *awaiting approval* email.

All other users with other email addresses need to be approved by an admin.

One potential solution I've thought of is to act on [hook_user_insert](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.api.php/function/hook_user_insert/7) to unblock and send the password email the user [hook_mail_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7) to disable the initial *awaiting approval* email.

I just feel this option is a bit hacky and I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing things.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [User Restrictions](http://drupal.org/project/user_restrictions) module for **Drupal 7** and [Access Rules](http://drupal.org/getting-started/6/admin/user/rules) for **Drupal 6**.

**UPDATE**

For registering users based on unique code check out [regcode](http://drupal.org/project/regcode) module